# Python Tkinter Slider Widget write Value over I2C

Tags: python, slider, i2c

Ok I have been searching for an example for a while now can not seem to find any examples of relaying the tkinter slider values over I2C to Arduino. So far I have not tried to communicate with the Arduino yet. Ill cross that bridge next; for now I just want to figure out how to write the slide widget values and send over I2C.

Here is a simple GUI slider widget in Python 2 with what I believe is the correct setup for I2C  communications. Ive updated the Rpi to set up the I2C as well. What I want to do in Arduino is simply read the values 0 to 180 for a servo control. It is important that it just writes values or in some way that can be used for an input. I  have other code in the arduino that drives the same servo, if other conditions are met and this would then be ignored.

```
from Tkinter import*
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

import smbus

bus = smbus.SMBus=(1)

SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x04



class App:



    def __init__(self, master):

        def SendScaleReading(self):
            S = scale.get()# Now how do we write this and get the Scale Value and send it??    
            bus(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('S'))#According to an example this should be 
                                        #"bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS, ord('S'))"

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        scale = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=180, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=SendScaleReading)
        scale.grid(row=1, column=1)



root = Tk()
root.wm_title('I2C servo control')
app = App(root)
root.geometry("200x50+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok a friend helped me out with and I wasnt too far off. Once I got this far I only a small issue with an IO error. I was getting [Errno 5] IO errors. Make sure you have a ground connected between the Arduino and Pi. When I searched this seemed to be overlooked by the many fixes out there offered. You need SDA, SLA and Gnd all connected.

So anyways here is the code that is working running an arduino i2c blink sketch. This will blink the led on pin 13 faster or slower based on the slider input in from the Rpi over I2C. I am going to try and write this code to control a servo next and if successful I will also post that code.

Rpi / python2 code below:

```
from Tkinter import*
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

import smbus

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x28



class App:



    def __init__(self, master):

        def SendScaleReading(self):
            S = scale.get()
            print("we have" );
            print( S )
            bus.write_byte_data(SLAVE_ADDRESS, S, S )

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        scale = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=180, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=SendScaleReading)
        scale.grid(row=1, column=1)



root = Tk()
root.wm_title('I2C servo control')
app = App(root)
root.geometry("200x50+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

Arduino i2c wire Blink sketch below:

```
#include <Wire.h>
// unique address for this I2C slave device
#define ADDRESS 0x28


// constants won't change. Used here to 
// set pin numbers:
const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// the follow variables is a long because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
volatile long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      
  Wire.begin(ADDRESS);                // join i2c bus with address #4

  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // register the request handler


}

//gets called when I2C read occurs
void requestEvent() {
//any request for data will return 0x14 (random number i picked for testing)
  Wire.write( 0x14  );
}

// get called when I2C write occurs
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
//just going to support 1 byte commands for now
  if (howMany  >0  ) {
    int c = Wire.read();
    interval = c * 10;
  }
  while (Wire.available() > 0 ) {
    Wire.read();
  }
}


void loop()
{
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.

  // check to see if it's time to blink the LED; that is, if the 
  // difference between the current time and last time you blinked 
  // the LED is bigger than the interval at which you want to 
  // blink the LED.
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED 
    previousMillis = currentMillis;   

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW)
      ledState = HIGH;
    else
      ledState = LOW;

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok well the servo code ended up being rather simple. Im sure it can be cleaned up so anyone with the know how please feel free to make improvements.

Arduino I2C Driven Servo Sketch is below:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>
// unique address for this I2C slave device
#define ADDRESS 0x28

Servo myservo;


int pos = 0;
void setup() {

myservo.attach(9);

  Wire.begin(ADDRESS);                // join i2c bus with address #4

  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // register the request handler


}

//gets called when I2C read occurs
void requestEvent() {
//any request for data will return 0x14 (random number i picked for testing)
  Wire.write( 0x14  );
}

// get called when I2C write occurs
void receiveEvent(int Pos) {

    int val = Wire.read();
    pos = val;

  while (Wire.available() > 0 ) {
    Wire.read();
  }
}


void loop()
{

myservo.write(pos);
delay(15);

}
```